# SIGSEGV handler works only 1 time. Why?

Tags: assembly, x86, signals, handler

I want to write a signal handler to catch `SIGSEGV` in assembly.
But I'm stuck because signal handler works only once.
Here I made simple example.

Here is whole code.

```
.global main

my_signalhandler:
 jmp here


install_signalhandler:
 .lcomm my_sigaction, 140                     
 .set SIGSEGV, 11                             
 .set SA_SIGINFO, 4                           
  pushl $my_signalhandler
  pushl $SIGSEGV                              
  call signal
  addl $8, %esp                              
  ret                              


main:
 call install_signalhandler   # install signal handler

here:
 jmp 0x11111111                # segmentation fault
```

In main, `install_signalhandler` function installs signal handler for `SIGSEGV`.
After that, `SIGSEGV` happens because of the invalid memory reference.


***- Expected Result:***
In this situation, I expected a infinite loop.
`main` → `here` → `my_signalhandler` → `here` → `my_signalhandler` → `here` ...


***- Real Result:***

```
$ ./test_signal
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The result was just Segmentation Fault. (not infinite loop.)
While I'm debugging, I found that `my_signalhandler` hits only 1 time.
After that, signal handler couldn't catch the signal.


***- Question:***
Why signal handler could not activated multiple time?

Comment: Because it can't detect a fault inside itself. You used `jmp here` which does **not** finish handling the signal. You need to use [sigreturn](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigreturn.2.html) and specify where normal execution should continue.

Comment: @Jester Oh yeah I should use `ret` at the end of signal handler to invoke sigreturn. Thank you for the comment.